# Pyqt5 SystemTrayIcon - Может ли он отображать в трее QLabel?

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyqt5

Может ли `SystemTrayIcon` при клике на него левой клавишей мыши отображать, например, `QLabel`, т.е. какую то информацию, а не контекстное меню?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Можно](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/e0f4f1d2b3e57e2bfa37bb81d06354b03b519a27/qt_custom_tray_menu.py). Используйте `QWidgetAction` и метод `setDefaultWidget` для установки виджета:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *


app = QApplication([])
app.setQuitOnLastWindowClosed(False)

icon = app.style().standardIcon(QStyle.SP_DirOpenIcon)
# Размещение своей иконки
# icon = QIcon('favicon.ico')

tray = QSystemTrayIcon(icon)

menu_widget = QLabel('<b>Hello</b>, World!')
menu_widget_action = QWidgetAction(menu_widget)
menu_widget_action.setDefaultWidget(menu_widget)

menu = QMenu()
menu.addAction(menu_widget_action)

tray.setContextMenu(menu)
tray.activated.connect(lambda x: menu.exec(tray.geometry().center()))

tray.show()

app.exec()
```

Выглядит так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Еще [пример](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/2d400f7cbd8fb31c880cfd317b82444f7744f642/currrent_job_report/main.py).

Comment: Спасибо тебе огромное!